# mongodb aggregate with time interval

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get the average temperature and humidity from my JSON response with an interval of 15 mins using the MongoDB Aggregate framework. I'm getting `SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):2:0`

This is my code

```
var datetime = new Date();
var interValue = 15*1000*60;
datetime.setHours(datetime.getHours() - 1 + interValue);
var endtime = new Date();
db.sensordata.aggregate([
{ $match : { datetime : { $gte : datetime, $lt: endtime } } },
{
        $group: {
            _id: {
                Time: "$datetime",
                Humidity: { "$avg" : "$humidity" },
                Temperature: { "$avg" : "$temperature"}
            },
        },
    },

    { 
        $project :{ _id : 1 , Humidity : 1, Temperature: 1 } },
                            { $limit : 10 },
                { $sort :  {"_id.Time":1, "Humidity":1, "Temperature": 1}}
            ])
```

this is my JSON response

```
[{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db63541472bf7683eb3c5"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:41:41.897Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db63a41472bf7683eb3c6"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:41:46.927Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db63f41472bf7683eb3c7"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:41:51.956Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db644483ab4f778a635bf"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:41:56.991Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("585db64a483ab4f778a635c0"), "datetime" : ISODate("2016-12-23T23:42:02.032Z"), "temperature" : 19, "humidity" : 23 }]
```

Also i'm getting an empty array

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the $group pipeline.

Grouping is done using **_id** field. The field(s) you want to use for grouping should only be placed in **_id** field.

If you want to group your results by **datetime** field, then use

```
$group: {
        "_id": {"Time":"$datetime"},                
        "Humidity": { "$avg" : "$humidity" },
        "Temperature": { "$avg" : "$temperature"}            
    }
```

See more on [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)

Comment: I'm still getting an empty array. Do you think my `datetime` and `interValue` are out of place?

Comment: `setHours()` on datetime with the given intervalue is resulting into a date which is around 100 years ahead of today's date. Adjust the calculation of dates according to your requirement. Please `console.log` the datetime and endtime before the query to check whether the correct values are being passed or not.

Comment: You're right. My time wasn't right. However what do you think I should do to add time intervals ?

Comment: What values of `datetime` and `endtime` do you need? or What time interval do you need for the query?

Comment: I need `datetime` to be 3 hours ago, `endtime` to be the current time. And an interval of 15 mins.

Comment: try this `var datetime = new Date();`
`datetime.setHours(datetime.getHours() - 3);`
`var endtime = new Date();`

Comment: This works perfectly. But i'm unable to add the time interval.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand the requirement of an interval. How the interval is going to affect the query?

Comment: I would like to find the avg humidity and temperature of the 15 mins  interval for an 3 hour reading.